# prevent submit if certain list option is selected

Tags: jquery

I use jquery 1.3.2.
I have a page with a select list and submit button. I want to prevent submitting if currently selected (not selected in html) option is equal to certain value (cancelled)?

Html:

```
 <form id="update-form">
  <select id="edit-status"> 
   <option value="cancelled">Cancelled</option>
   <option value="sent">Sent</option>
   <option value="pending" selected="selected">Pending</option>
  </select>

<input id="submitbutton" value="Update" type="submit">
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#edit-status").change(function () {
if (
    $('#edit-status').val() == 'cancelled'
) {
    $("#update-form").submit(function(e) {
        alert('alert');
        e.preventDefault(e);
    });
 }
});
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q9Mh9/1/

The code works but only if I select 'cancelled' value for the first time. After that, no matter option I choose, after submitting I always get alert. Thank you for help.

Comment: I stopped reading at `"I use jquery 1.3.2"`, why would you use a library that is half a decade old ?

Comment: @adeneo Drupal 6 unfortunately...

Comment: You know you have syntax errors, the if statement isn't closed ?

Comment: Oh wait, it is, just bad formatting !

Comment: Try it like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/q9Mh9/2/**

Comment: Why are you binding events inside of events?

Comment: @adeneo yes that works, what was I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the form submit event incorrectly. In your code, the form.Submit event is bound when the dropdown value is changed for the first time. Once the event is bound, it will fire every time the update button is clicked.

The following solution should work for you.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q9Mh9/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#update-form").submit(function (e) {
        if ($('#edit-status').val() == 'cancelled') {
            alert('alert');
        }
        e.preventDefault(e);
    });
    $("#edit-status").change(function () {
        $("#update-form").submit();
        return false;
    });
});
```